# React state is not getting Updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, state, jsx

Here I need to get the updated states of input in the console but I get an error setSavedinput is not defined whenever give something in the input.

```js
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
const blankinput = () => {
  const [savedContent, setsavedContent] = useState("");
};
const onChangeHandler = (e) => {
  setsavedContent(e.target.value);
  console.log(savedContent);
};
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input type="Text" onChange={onChangeHandler}></input>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The code you posted makes no mention of `setSavedInput`, so I'm not sure where you are getting that error from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hooks (like `useState`) and the associated functions that modify them (like your `onChangeHandler`) need to go inside the function component, not outside. The following should work:

```js
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

export default function App() {
  const [savedContent, setsavedContent] = useState("");
  const onChangeHandler = (e) => {
    setsavedContent(e.target.value);
    console.log(e.target.value); // savedContent doesn't change immediately
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input type="Text" onChange={onChangeHandler}></input>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because state only has new value when component re render. So you should move `console.log` to `useEffect` to check the new value when component re-render.

```
const onChangeHandler = (e) => {
  setsavedContent(e.target.value);
};

useEffect(() => {
  console.log(savedContent);
}, [savedContent]);
```

Answer (score 0):

### **You've got a few issues with your code, only using `hooks` inside your component body**

Also, if you want to see the latest update of your state, put it right before the return function.

You won't see the latest update of your state because of [Reactjs's batching mechanism](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous). and state update is asynchronous.

**Here is a snippet with a few corrections of your code.**

```js
function App() {
  const [savedContent, setsavedContent] = React.useState('');
  const onChangeHandler = (e) => {
    setsavedContent(e.target.value);
  };
  console.log(savedContent);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input type="Text" onChange={onChangeHandler} />
    </div>
  );
}

 const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
    ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
    <div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your state is defined inside of the function blankInput. Due to scoping in JavaScript that code is unreachable, move it outside of that function to avoid the error.

However in order for the input element to render correctly, it’s important you set the input’s value to the savedContent state.

`<input type="Text" onChange={onChangeHandler} value={savedContent} />`

That way you aren’t updating the input element directly, instead you’re updating the state which triggers a re-render from React.